# Relative v.s. Absolute positioning of container and contained divisions

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the `<ul></ul>`s under each body part ("Right Hand" and "Left Hand" in the figure below) to stay aligned with the the body part as the user resizes the browser window.  But currently, they seem to be staying aligned with the outer-most container `<div>` `solo-figure` and not with the image `<div>` `figure`.

That is, the image `figure.gif` stays centered in the in the container `<div>` `solo-figure` when the browser window is resized, as I want it to, but the `<ul></ul>`s stay 100px and 500px, respectively, to the left of the left edge of `<div>` `solo-figure`.

How do I adjust the `positions` of styles so that the `<ul></ul>`s stay under the body parts in the image?

[image]

```
<style>
    #body_Belt { border:none; left:100px; position:absolute; top:340px; }
    #body_Feet { border:none; left:100px; position:absolute; top:100px; }
    #body_LeftHand { border:none; left:500px; position:absolute; top:340px; }
    #body_LeftShoulder { border:none; left:100px; position:absolute; top:100px; }
    #body_RightHand { border:none; left:100px; position:absolute; top:340px; }
    #body_RightShoulder { border:none; left:100px; position:absolute; top:100px; }
    #body_Torso { border:none; left:100px; position:absolute; top:100px; }`

    div.figure { position:relative; width:auto; }
    div.possessions { text-align:left; position:absolute; }
    div.solo-figure { height:710px; margin:auto; }
</style>

<div class="solo-figure">
    <div class="figure">
        <img src="img/figure.gif" height="700">

        <div class="possessions" id="body_Torso">
        </div><!-- class="possessions" id="Torso"-->
        
        <div class="possessions" id="body_RightShoulder">
        </div><!-- class="possessions" id="RightShoulder"-->
            
        <div class="possessions" id="body_LeftShoulder">    
        </div><!-- class="possessions" id="LeftShoulder"-->

        <div class="possessions" id="body_RightHand">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="tooltip">Plastic Bag<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="img/cards/items/BagPlastic.gif" /></span></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><div class="tooltip">Plastic Bag<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="img/cards/items/BagPlastic.gif" /></span></div></li>
                        <li><div class="tooltip">Canned Vegetables<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="img/cards/items/CannedVegetable.gif" /></span></div></li>
                        <li><div class="tooltip">Canned Meat<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="img/cards/items/CannedMeat.gif" /></span></div></li>
                        <li><div class="tooltip">Plastic Bottle<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="img/cards/items/BottlePlastic.gif" /></span></div></li>
                        <li><div class="tooltip">Plastic Bottle<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="img/cards/items/BottlePlastic.gif" /></span></div></li>
                        <li><div class="tooltip">Plastic Bottle<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="img/cards/items/BottlePlastic.gif" /></span></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- class="possessions" id="RightHand"-->

        <div class="possessions" id="body_LeftHand">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="tooltip">Pump Action Shotgun<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="img/cards/items/ShotgunSB.gif" /></span></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><div class="tooltip">Shotgun Shell<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="img/cards/items/Shotgun-Round.gif" /></span></div></li>
                        <li><div class="tooltip">Shotgun Shell<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="img/cards/items/Shotgun-Round.gif" /></span></div></li>
                        <li><div class="tooltip">Shotgun Shell<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="img/cards/items/Shotgun-Round.gif" /></span></div></li>
                        <li><div class="tooltip">Shotgun Shell<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="img/cards/items/Shotgun-Round.gif" /></span></div></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- class="possessions" id="LeftHand"-->

        <div class="possessions" id="body_Feet">                
        </div><!-- class="possessions" id="Feet"-->

    </div><!-- class="figure" -->
</div><!-- class="solo-figure" -->
```

Comment: Could you create a Snippet with the image so it's easier for other people to work out a solution?

Comment: My first guess would be to try using percentages rather than pixels.

Comment: I don't know if this will give you what you want @RichardHunter, but try https://jsfiddle.net/pjamesnorris25/tr0e6u57/21/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use percentages for positioning which are relative to the image container. As you resize the page, the image will resize whilst keeping its aspect ratio. The info panels will keep their size, but be anchored to the equivalent position within the image.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.solo-figure {
  background: green;
}

.figure {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background: pink;
  width: auto;
  border: solid 2px black;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.main-image {
  width: 100%;
}
.possessions {
  border: solid 2px dodgerblue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  top: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 8px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#body_LeftHand {
  background: salmon;
  width: 150px;
  left: 90%;
}

#body_RightHand {
  left: 10%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.tooltip {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltipimage {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltipimage {
  margin-top: -75px;
  visibility: visible;
}

.zoom_small {
  transition: transform .2s;
  width: 88px;
}

.zoom_small:hover {
  transform: scale(3.0);
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="solo-figure">
  <div class="figure">
    <img class="main-image" src="https://www.ocetacea.net/BoyAndDog/img/figure.gif">

    <div class="possessions" id="body_RightHand">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="tooltip">Plastic Bag<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="https://www.ocetacea.net/BoyAndDog/img/cards/items/BagPlastic.gif" /></span></div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div class="tooltip">Plastic Bag<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="https://www.ocetacea.net/BoyAndDog/img/cards/items/BagPlastic.gif" /></span></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="tooltip">Canned Vegetables<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="https://www.ocetacea.net/BoyAndDog/img/cards/items/CannedVegetable.gif" /></span></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="tooltip">Canned Meat<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="img/cards/items/CannedMeat.gif" /></span></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="tooltip">Plastic Bottle<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="img/cards/items/BottlePlastic.gif" /></span></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="tooltip">Plastic Bottle<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="https://www.ocetacea.net/BoyAndDog/img/cards/items/BottlePlastic.gif" /></span></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="tooltip">Plastic Bottle<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="https://www.ocetacea.net/BoyAndDog/img/cards/items/BottlePlastic.gif" /></span></div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- class="possessions" id="RightHand"-->

    <div class="possessions" id="body_LeftHand">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="tooltip">Pump Action Shotgun<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="https://www.ocetacea.net/BoyAndDog/img/cards/items/ShotgunSB.gif" /></span></div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div class="tooltip">Shotgun Shell<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="https://www.ocetacea.net/BoyAndDog/img/cards/items/Shotgun-Round.gif" /></span></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="tooltip">Shotgun Shell<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="https://www.ocetacea.net/BoyAndDog/img/cards/items/Shotgun-Round.gif" /></span></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="tooltip">Shotgun Shell<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="https://www.ocetacea.net/BoyAndDog/img/cards/items/Shotgun-Round.gif" /></span></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="tooltip">Shotgun Shell<span class="tooltipimage"><img class="zoom_small card" src="https://www.ocetacea.net/BoyAndDog/img/cards/items/Shotgun-Round.gif" /></span></div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- class="possessions" id="LeftHand"-->

  </div>
  <!-- class="figure" -->
</div>
<!-- class="solo-figure" -->
```

Comment: Thanks, @RichardHunter! But the aspect ratio does not remain constant--the salmon colored region, i.e. gets narrower and wider but maintaining the same height as I resize the window--see: [link](ocetacea.net/BoyAndDog/figure-test.html)

Comment: I must admit, I don't fully understand quite what is required. What I'd suggest is try to create a Snippet yourself and then we can take a look at it.

Comment: Richard, my apologies.  I'm a Mac user, do my development work on Safari and then make modifications as necessary for Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.  Then I pull out an old Windows laptop and make modifications as necessary for IE.  I just tested your solution on every of these browser but IE, and it works as you claim; it's only on Safari that the image doesn't maintain its aspect ratio--I don't know yet why this is.

So I'm going to mark your solution as a good one; thanks!